# To define an object in a constructor in Serializable class

Tags: java, android, json, serializable

I have a JSON response like below image, and I have made a serializable class named as `Project`

[image: JSON Response]

In the image, I have two objects (`emergency_contact`, and `secondary_owner`) inside my an array of one object. I'm trying to figure out whether what to do in order to define the object, since I want that details to be present inside my constructor.

I have done this so far:

```
public class Project implements Serializable {
   public int id;
   public String name;
   public String additional_information;
   //Now what to do Emergency contact

   public Project(int id, String name, String additional_information){

   }
}
```

I have thought of doing this, `public EmergencyContact emergency = new EmergencyContact(param1, param2)`.

And make a new class named as `EmergencyContact`, and do a getter and setter for the params. But after doing this, I'm still confused, how would I define it my constructor?

I know I'm close, but I need some help on that.

Comment: `public Project(int id, String name, String additional_information, EmergencyContact emergencyContact)` - same as any other field in constructor

Comment: You have to define classes for both nested objects as well.

Comment: Could you show it to me in respect of code please @IvanKaloyanov?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You need to have a:

```
public class EmergencyContact implements Serializable {

   public String name;
   public String number;

   public EmergencyContact(String name, String number){
     // assign fields 
   }
}
```

and one for the owner:

```
public class EmergencyOwner implements Serializable {

   public String name;
   public String number;

   public EmergencyOwner(String name, String number){
     // assign the fields
   }
}
```

then in your `Project` class you can add fields of these classes:

```
public class Project implements Serializable {
   public int id;
   public String name;
   public String additional_information;
   public EmergencyContact emergency_contact;
   public EmergencyOwner emergency_owner;

   public Project(int id, String name, String additional_information, EmergencyContact emergency_contact, EmergencyOwner emergency_owner){
     // assign the fields here as well
   }
}
```

that's it. If that's an answer to the question consider to delete this question as it is a duplicated on a 100% :)

Answer (score 1):

As a note, to be correctly from the point of clean code parameters, the fields should be private in a class, and use setters / getters to set/retrieve values from/to those fields.

```
public class Project implements Serializable {
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String additional_information;
   private EmergencyContact emergency_contact;
   private SecondaryOwner secondary_owner;

   public Project(int id, String name, String additional_information, EmergencyContact emergencyContact, SecondaryOwner secondaryOwner){
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
       this.additional_information = additional_information;
       this.emergency_contact = emergencyContact;
       this.secondary_owner = secondaryOwner;
   }
}
```

You will define the other two classes the same way. Now, you are probably confused about the constructor of EmergencyContact & SecondaryOwner classes.. You can device both default constructors (without parameters) and a custom one(with parameters to it, just as the one above). If you use the default constructor, make sure to set values to the fields in the object, as following :

```
EmergencyContact emergencyContact = new EmergencyContact();
emergencyContact.setName("the name");
emergencyContact.setNumber("a number");
```

then you can use this object in the constructor of `Project` class

I hope it was clear enough, for any other clarifications feel free to ask.

Happy coding <3